# Minimizing cross section area of the intersection between a plane and mesh

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, intersection-theory

I have a 3D triangular mesh and a cutting plane. I want to minimize the area of the cut intersection by rotating the normal of the plane.

The image shows the cross section of the cut and the mesh.

[image]

You can see the original mesh before the cut here.

[image]

Let's assume the cutting plane has a point A and a normal N. I want to change normal N in a way that the yellow area is minimum.

Comment: Cut perpendicular to the cylinder.

Comment: Well that is the solution, but how to automatically find the perpendicular cut? Not that the cylinder will have U shape turns later on. It is not always straight. Also not always a cylinder could have different shape.

Comment: Well it depends on the information to which you have access. For a cylinder, every triangle in the mesh exists in a plane in 2D (infinite directions); the direction common to all triangles is the normal.
If your shape is freeform, you basically have an optimization problem over an unspecified function. It's like a question "Is person X a man ?"; without extra information, it is not answerable (though you could design a gradient descent type algorithm to solve this problem for you in the general case).

Comment: @LionKing How is my answer

Comment: @TristanDuquesne Could you elaborate a little more regarding the general case. The only information that I have is that the cut will create a convex polygon. I want the area of that polygon to be minimized (or close to minimum) by tilting the cutting plane.

Comment: since you have a mesh instead of a cylinder i do not see how this should be archieved without optimization. you could do some heuristics to guess a reasonable starting point (e.g. the heuristics that your mesh is actually a cylinder and then somehow calculate its normal) and then do gradient descent, newton, bfgs, trust-region or one of the heuristic optimization algorithms such as evolutionary algorithms. IMPORTANT: the function you minimize (area of cut) will be continuous but the differential might not, at least i dont see why. hence the descent methods are not guaranteed to converge.

Comment: how do you end up with the triangulation? if you get there by selecting nodes from a level set of a level set function, you could overcvome the possible disontinuous differential resulting from the discrete triangulation by formulating the area-of-cut in terms of the level set function instead the triangulation and end up with superlinear convergency.

Comment: @Max's answer is excellent. To define your transformation problem, you must find the point where the normal is set; then the normal's direction. I suppose you'll be predefining the section point, and optimizing the three coordinates of the normal vector. Then your problem is optimization over a function of $R^3 \to R$, where the output is the resulting polygon's area. What you can do is do some sampling for your normal, finding the areas, and run a gradient descent, etc. Or, if you want a global minimum, you use these samples to draw a manifold for your function, and use discrete Morse theory.

Comment: @Max I get the triangulation from STL or any other format that has tessellation in it.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne I only need to find a local minimum. I think a gradient descent could give me a good result, but I am not sure if it would be performant enough. I have to calculate the intersection of the cut with the triangles for each step, which could end up being very computational expensive.

Comment: How long, on average, does the calculation of such an intersection last ? How many do you have to do, on average ?

Comment: @TristanDuqesne the hard part is writing down the area function (efficiently, without too much looping through all polygons), not its integration it in an optimization algorithm.

Comment: the comment shoud be addressed to @LionKing, sorry for that.

Comment: @LionKing Just came across this: https://www.quantamagazine.org/statistics-postdoc-tames-decades-old-geometry-problem-20210301/ It might interest you.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne It depends on the number of triangles and how well I manage to create some sort of spatial structure to only check the triangles that makes sense. However, even with that I have to do hundreds of these optimizations. That's why it needs to be really efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Warning: I only have negligible experience in computational geometry. But I think this is an interesting engineering problem that worth more discussion. So I leave my incomplete idea below.)

---

#### Main idea

Consider the function $\phi:S^2\to \mathbb R$ that sends the unit normal of the cutting plane to the corresponding cross section area. Then $\phi$ is not differentiable only when the plane passing through a vertex of the mesh (*). (Not checked but seems likely.)

[image: phi values]

[image: cusp on s2]

The plane already have a fixed point in your scenario. If the plane is also forced to contain a given vertex, then the unit normal would trace out a great circle on $S^2$. By (*), non-differentiable points are on the red curve in the following picture.

[image: red curve]

For each point in the mesh, draw the corresponding red curve. An intersection of two red curves reveals the normal direction when the plane passes through two vertice.

[image: all red curves]

(For $S^2$) We are now looking for a local minimum of $\phi$ over the sphere (or hemisphere). IMO, we can first move along the red curves to find a minimal red-curve intersection point.

(For mesh) This corresponds to rotate a plane, from one vertex to another, while the other vertex fixed.

[image: steps]

(For computation) Find out the four possible new vertice by finding out the smallest rotation angles below. Then compute the cross sectional areas, and select the one with smallest area.

[image: view point]

Repeat the step to obtain a "local minimal cut through two points".

[image: vertex final]

This may not be a true minimum. Take the long prism for example, the minimal cut does not pass through a vertex.

[image: long prism]

The hard thing is to find some methods to improve. Some possible ways are

1. subdivide some necessary facet and repeat the fore-mensioned method, or
2. descent into a nearby region,

,or 3. use the least square method to guess.

Let me explain (3) first. If we have a shape that resemble a tube or prism, then we fit the face normals with a plane, and use the direction of that plane. (Or should we just do this at the very beginning?)

[image: fitting plane]

---

Supppose we have a "local minimal cut through two points". Then, toward which direction should we descent or subdivide?

(For $S^2$) Now there are 8 directions for us to move in. But maybe it's not good to choose a vertex as the rotation pivot, so only 4 directions are remaining.

(For mesh) The 8 directions correspond to the following 8 ways to rotate the plane. So you can try some descent method in these direction.

[image: 8 directions]

One way is, in each direction we can find out the smallest angle $\theta$ to rotate the plane without passing through another vertex. Then rotate $\frac \theta 2$, and so on.

Or can we directly derive a formula for the cross sectional area of a prism? I gave up to derive that formula.

#### The unfinished computation

We write the plane as $ax+by=z$ (fixed point = origin) so that it may be easier to differentiate the area w.r.t $a,b$.

An edge $\overline{(p_1,p_2,p_3),(q_1,q_2,q_3)}$ of the mesh pass through the plane if $(p_3-ap_1-bp_2)(q_3-aq_1-bq_2)<0$. The the intersection (yellow dots) of the edge with the plane would be $$\frac{(p_3-ap_1-bp_2)(q_1,q_2,q_3)-(q_3-aq_1-bq_2)(p_1,p_2,p_3)}{(p_3-ap_1-bp_2)-(q_3-aq_1-bq_2)}$$

whose coordinates are $\frac{\text{linear function of a,b}}{\text{linear function of a,b}}$.

[image: prism]

Find out these yellow dots and sort out the order (need some pre-processing about edges and faces) so that we could write down the cross products to calculate the area as $$\text{Area} = \frac 12 \left|v_1\times v_2 + v_2\times v_3+\cdots + v_n\times v_1\right|.$$

This is a quantity $$\textstyle\frac 12\sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{quadratic function of a,b}}{\text{quadratic function of a,b}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\text{quadratic function of a,b}}{\text{quadratic function of a,b}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\text{quadratic function of a,b}}{\text{quadratic function of a,b}}\right)^2}$$ depends on $a$. The coefficients are some constants involving $(p_1,p_2,p_3), (q_1, q_2, q_3), ...$ and $(r_1,r_2,r_3)$. But It seems too messy to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

As cvanaret says, just cut perpendicular to the mesh, because it is basically a cylinder. Here is a proof of why a cut perpendicular to the cylinder yields the smallest cross section.

First, assume we cut the cylinder at an angle that is not perpendicular to the cylinder's length. This is what it should look like

[image]

The cross section is an ellipse. Since the ellipse does not change horizontally, its horizontal length $a$ is just equal to the radius $r$ of the cylinder. However, since we cut at an angle, the ellipses top is tilted back, and its bottom is tilted forward, so the vertical length $b$ is affected. From a side view, we get this picture.

[image]

The length $2l$ represents how much the cylinder's shape protrudes forwards due to the angled cut. From the Pythagorean theorem, we get that $ b = \sqrt{r^2+l^2}$. Also, $\sqrt{r^2+l^2} \gt \sqrt{r^2}$ because $l \gt 0$, meaning they can never be equal. Simplifying the previous inequality, we get $ b > r$.

Now, lets compare the cross sectional areas. If we cut it perpendicular to the cylinder's length, the area of the cross section is just the area of a circle with the cylinder's radius, or $\pi r^2$.

The cross sectional area of an angled cut cylinder is an ellipse with area $\pi ab$.

We will now prove that $\pi ab > \pi r^2$.

First off, we know that $b>r$. Now multiply both sides by $\pi r$ to get $\pi br > \pi r^2$. We know that $a=r$, so this inequality becomes $\pi ab > \pi r^2$. Thus, we have proven that the cross-sectional area of an angle-cut cylinder is greater than that of a perpendicular cut cylinder. That means to minimize the cross-sectional area, you need to cut perpendicular to the cylinder's length to get a circle cross-section instead of an ellipse one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the general case it can have other shapes. What I have is just the intersection of the cut with the mesh. Which leads to the yellow area. This yellow area as you can see represent a polygon. I want the area of this polygon to be minimize by tilting the cutting plane. Even if we assume it can only be cylinder, how can I find the cut perpendicular to it? Remember, that I only have triangular surface mesh.